# How to store and pop uint8_t from/to uint32_t asynchronously in C++?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, data-structures, stdvector, nodemcu

I'm working on a MCU, enhancing the [library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Thermal-Printer-Library), making it non-blocking.

It already blocks code using `while` loop for certain times.

I've tweaked the library to remove all these blockings, sniff out all what should be sent to a `std::vector<uint8_t> internalBuffer`. and used `micros()` to asynchronously send bytes through stream output in loop().

I'm Enhancing that by converting `std::vector<uint8_t> internalBuffer` to `std::vector<uint32_t>` to take way less space (using ESP8266 with aligned 4 bytes).

I know how to store and extract `uint8_t` to `uint32_t`, But when it comes to **Asynchronous** store and extract, Here comes un-known probabilities to me.

Because storing and extracting `uint8_t` are asynchronous, storing is anytime, extracting is constrained by time interval.

For what's worth mentioning : I've already done storing, but I don't have a complete extraction code.

```
void Pos_Printer::storeInBuffer(uint8_t c)
{
    uint32_t longInt = 0UL;
    if (excessBytesInBuffer == 0)
    {
      longInt = c;
    }
    else
    {
      longInt = internalBuffer.back();
      internalBuffer.pop_back();
      longInt = longInt << 8 * excessBytesInBuffer + c;
    }
    excessBytesInBuffer++;
    excessBytesInBuffer %= 4;

    internalBuffer.push_back(longInt);
}
```

Uncompleted extraction (at CLASS::loop()) :

```
  if (micros() - resumeTime > 0 && internalBuffer.size())
  {
    uint32_t longInt = 0UL;
    uint8_t byteToSend = 0;

    if(internalBuffer.size() == 1)      
    {                   //Work on excessBytesInBuffer
      longInt = internalBuffer.at(0);
      if(excessBytesInBuffer)
      {                         //What if remained 1 and stored +3 Bytes after this ?
        byteToSend = (longInt >> 8 * excessBytesInBuffer) & 0xFF;

      }
    }
    else
    {    

    }

    stream->write(byteToSend);
    internalBuffer.erase(internalBuffer.begin()); //Uncompleted 
    lastWritingTime = micros();
  }
```

Another solution : I've thought of another solution, To store 1 of 4 bytes of (uint32_t) to keep track how many bytes stored (from 1 to 3). But that's a big loss if wanted to optimize storing an image to the library (as example).

Comment: I don't understand. Why would `std::vector<uint8_t>` take more space than `std::vector<unit32_t>`? It makes no sense.

Comment: Yeah, second the confusion. If anything, the uint32 vector may take more space if the requested memory has to be 4-byte aligned. The uint8 vector wouldn't need to be 4-byte aligned in memory.

Comment: It seems you're trying to possibly save some number of bytes on the heap (unclear how many) at the cost of much more computation (read last byte, modify last byte, push back last byte) and larger code. From where I stand this seems wrong.

Comment: AFAIK least location to be located in ESP8266 is 32 bit. Correct me please if wrong... If true : storing 4 bytes into one 32 bit int, really helps when it comes in sending a large image to the stream(>4kB for example)

Comment: @JohnFilleau What could be the code snippet to test out this info ?

Comment: I've just test that out using `memory = sizeof(vec[0]) * vec.size()` inside a loop with elements are push_back'ed. That appears it's optimized at the byte level, not just 4 bytes as was assumed.. I just want to know whether my test right and firm ?

Answer (score 0):

Just like you keep `excessBytesInBuffer` in storing, you need something like `missingBytesInBuffer` in extraction. Then you would only do `internalBuffer.erase(internalBuffer.begin());` when `missingBytesInBuffer` is 4.

You could speed things up if you store four bytes at a time, assuming you have them all on the calling side.

Similarly, you can extract four bytes at a time and keep them in a local buffer (cache).

Comment: The issue in relying on missingBytesInBuffer alone, Is the case where only 1-3 bytes are stored, How to keep track of bytes stored ? if it was 2 at the extraction and asynchronously stored 3 bytes. Here It misses it up... I think the cache idea could be the beginning of the solution.

Comment: @HamzaHajeir - I don't see a problem; `missingBytesInBuffer` is applicable to the first element of your vector, while `excessBytesInBuffer` - to the last. If there is only one element - the valid bytes are `[missingBytesInBuffer..excessBytesInBuffer-1]`. If `missingBytesInBuffer == excessBytesInBuffer` in that case - your vector is empty and you can reset both of them to `0`.